# Using scipy.io.loadmat to load .mat files that have the machineformat of `ieee-le.l64`

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I trying to load a `.mat` file using the `scipy.io.loadmat` function. The `.mat` file has the machineformat of `ieee-le.l64`:

```
>> fileID = fopen('matlab.mat')

fileID =

     4

>> [filename, permission, machineformat] = fopen(fileID)

filename =

    '/Users/uchidatakaya/Dropbox/am1xi1_for_takaya/matlab.mat'


permission =

    'r'


machineformat =

    'ieee-le.l64'
```

which corresponds to "IEEE floating point with little-endian byte ordering and 64-bit long data type". It seems that the `scipy.io.loadmat` doesn't support this data format (I could only find the options of `native', 'big-endian' or 'little-endian') but is there a work around for this? When I load in the data:

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat(op.join(ddir,'matlab'), appendmat=True, byte_order='little')
```

I get complex numbers with the `a` and `b` being integers for (`a+bi`), whereas in the actual dataset `a` and `b` are double precision real numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get if you don't explicitly specify `byte_order`?

Comment: I get the same result, integer coefficients.

Comment: How is the `*.mat` file generated? A reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: I just use the `save` function without any flags: `save('matlab.mat','beta0','F','dz','nz','psik','rho','ubar','wk','z')`

Comment: (1) Can you post the MAT file on Dropbox or something for us to investigate. (2) MAT files should abstract away endianness. What happens when you just use `scipy.io.loadmat`? (3) How big is the MAT file?